# how to solve this : Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to clone one of MERN stack project called Emaily But I'm facing an error

```
Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
```

My Action is given bellow ,

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { FETCH_USER, FETCH_SURVEYS } from './types';

export const fetchUser = () => async dispatch => {
  const res = await axios.get('/api/current_user');

  dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove **async** keyword from dispatch.

```
export const loadUsers = () => dispatch => {   dispatch({ type: LOAD_USERS_LOADING });
```